# Could not read data from excel in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to read data from excel file that I have been already created.
But new corrupted file with the same name be always created in the same path while running the code. And also getting the error as "The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly."

Here is my code

```
public void readdata()
        {
           //var fileName = string.Format("{0}\\C:\\Indputdata.xls", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            //var con = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", fileName);

            string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\\Inputdata.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(con))
            {
              connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection);
                using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        var row1Col0 = dr[0];
                        Console.WriteLine(row1Col0);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the name of your first document's sheet?

Comment: Anyway, if you have the document that was created with MS Excel of different language than English, then you have to use the localized names of sheets or rename them.

Comment: Sheet1. I didnt rename

Comment: I also changed the sheet name as DATA and change it the code also.But I have the same error.

Comment: @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\\Inputdata.xls... ? 

Try @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Inputdata.xls...

Comment: Please, compare your connection string with this
http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: tried this but having the same error

Comment: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\Inputdata.xls;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";

Comment: i tried this and having error as "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'DATA$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'DATA$' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Excel 2007 and 2010 you need to use the `ACE OLEDB` Provider.The `Jet OLEDB` Provider has been deprecated and does not support Office version 2007 or higher files.

Try this  `Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"`

```
 Data Source=D:\Inputdata.xls;
```

---

```
string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Inputdata.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
```

[Excel Connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)

[check](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Comment: I am using excel 2010 version. So did i want to change anything in the properties?

Comment: @NithyaIyappan use ACE OLEDB Provider.instead of OLEDB.4.0;..Check i have updated

Comment: I used the ACE OLEDB Provider. But having the error as "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'DATA$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'DATA$' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator."

Comment: @NithyaIyappan http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/4b4dceed-a45b-4d6d-b53b-4e584244f65b/the-microsoft-access-database-engine-could-not-find-the-object-make-sure-the-object-exists-and

Comment: @NithyaIyappan If my answer is useful make my answer as useful

Comment: Check with your link. And my excel properties have read option in disable format.So I go through it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This error usually happens due to the incorrect path. make sure the file path is correct and you have the sheet1 in that file